# JQuery Sortable over Bootstrap rows

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some bootstrap HTML, there are two rows.

On the top row, there are two divs in different columns, these are sortable and work without issue.

The problem is that I cannot get the 2nd row to be sortable with the 1st row. In other words, I need a way to be able to make the divs inside rows 1 and 2 sortable between each other. (Drag a div from row 1 to row 2)

You can see that 1 and 2 are sortable but not with the others (3 and 4) in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CsFpn/3/

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="sortable">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c1" id="c1">1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c2" id="c2">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="sortable">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c3" id="c3">3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c4" id="c4">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `.sortable()` on the container element (which is not in your example), and set [items](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option to `.col-md-6`.

Than you have to use the [change](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change) event to rearrange elements between rows if a `change` occurs during sort.

Using your markup it would be:

(I've changed the two `id="sortable"` to `class="sortable"`)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.container').sortable({
            items: '.col-md-6',
            change: function(e, ui) {
                // Rearrange your columns between rows here
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sortable">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="c1" id="c1">1</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="c2" id="c2">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="sortable">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="c3" id="c3">3</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="c4" id="c4">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.  First, HTML ids must be unique.  Second, you need to connect the sortables together as shown in [this jQuery sortable example](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists).

I forked your jsfiddle to demonstrate how to make it work:  http://jsfiddle.net/puh2r3vn/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c1" id="c1">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c2" id="c2">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c3" id="c3">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="c4" id="c4">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: That is limited to the row length in this case 2 sortable items, how could you  sort cross rows? :)